# CSS make div clickable under overlapping div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Behold the image.

[image]

I have 2 divs. One is a gray box and the other is a bordered div overlapping it.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="border-overlap"></div>
  <div class="box">
     There's text here and some links which should be clickable.  
  </div>
</div>
```

The issue: I cannot click any links inside the gray box because the bordered div overlaps it.

How can I make the links in the gray box clickable through the bordered div?

I have to accomplish this without:

- Wrapping the gray box in the bordered div
- Giving the links inside the gray box a greater z-index because those links will then overlap the border (See image. The word "box", even if it is a link and will be clicked, should stay behind the border)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could add

```
.border-overlap {
   pointer-events: none;
}
```

so any click event on that element will be captured from the element below

As a side note I'd suggest to use a pseudoelement instead of an empty element just for styling purpose

```css
.box {
  background: #ccc;
  width: 12rem;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  margin: 2rem;
  position: relative;
}

.box::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  inset: 0;
  border: 5px yellowgreen solid;
  transform: translate(-1rem, -1rem);
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
     There's text here and some links which should be clickable.  
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool. And this solution that you suggest works in all browsers and mobile?

Comment: All browsers from IE11. https://caniuse.com/pointer-events

Comment: This is the one!!